# Why doesn't indexof detect a space in my string?

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to create a verification script to my form... The "Name, Last name and Mobile" are working but The `indexof(" ")` is not working Well I put a space on the first password and I didn't put any in the Confirm Password but the form still submitted?

*"f" is the name of the form*

**JS:**

```
function Verif1() {
  if (f.Name.value.length < 3) {
    return false;
  } else if (f.LastName.value.length < 3) {
    return false;
  } else if (f.Mobile.value.length != 8 || f.Mobile.value < 1) {
    return false;
  } else if (f.Password.value.length < 6 || f.Password.value.indexof(" ") > 0) {
    return false;
  } else if (f.CPassword !== f.Password) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check the console for errors and debug your code before posting here

Comment: I did check the console It just passed ( submitted )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All function names are case sensitive in JavaScript.

Rename your function `indexof` to `indexOf`.